# ARkit objects moving with camera instead of staying static

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am just getting started with ARkit and Unity and tried the most basic thing, placing an object in the scene. I am placing the object 3 units in front of the camera and not attaching it to any anchor or generated plane. When I move my camera the object also slightly moves, which I believe should not happen.

How do I optimize the anchoring of the object in the AR space?

Answer (score 2):

At the start of AR, objects should move with the camera until ARKit is able to "initialize" and get its bearing.

After initialization, objects may move a bit as ARKit's understand of the world improves or if its view is obscured, etc.

However, large-scale movements should not be a common occurrence and small movements are just a nature of the tech right now.

If the "pre-initialization" movement is unsettling, you can consider hiding the object until the ARSession has initialized.

I've not actually used Unity with ARKit, so I can't help you with code there, but feel free to try out [Viro React](https://viromedia.com/viroreact/) which is an cross-platform mobile AR/VR framework that lets you build AR/VR apps in React Native (and it's free!).

Comment: On top of this, when you add an object 3 units ahead (3 meters ahead essentially) just moving forward and back slightly isn't that large relative to the distance to the object, so it might seem like it moves along with the phone due to this.

Comment: So you're saying it's a known bug of ARKit that models have small movements instead of remaining perfectly still? Just want to confirm it's not a code/configuration issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, small adjustments/movements are to be expected since at the end of the day, the only input is 1 camera + gyro & accelerometer data. One way to confirm is to try out other people's apps on the store like:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viro.figment

Comment: Is there any way to know once ARKit has finished initializing? Any delegate method we can use?